# Opening a JSON file converting to dictionary in a class

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary

I am opening and reading in a json file called, say, `my_file.json` located at `..\config\my_file.json` in a python file called `run_test.py`. Ultimately, I would like to turn the JSON object into a python dictionary and do other stuff with it in python. I am running the below code from my terminal to execute the class:

`python -c "from run_test import Update; x = Update('my_file.json'); print(x.why())"`

This returns:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: why() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_details'`

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. When I run (with `return f` in the body of read_file):

`python -c "from run_test import Update; x = Update('my_file.json'); print(x.read_file())`

This prints the dictionary I need. However, I would like to pass it to why so I can do other stuff with that dictionary. Yet, when I pass `f` to why, I get the above error. **Why?**

Here is the class I'm using:

```
import json

class Update:
    def __init__(self, config_file_name):
        self.config_file_name = config_file_name

    def why(self, file_details):
        return file_details

    def read_file(self):
        f = json.load(open('..\config\\' + self.config_file_name))
        self.why(f)
```

Comment: `why()` takes a `file_details` argument. You care calling it without one `print(x.why())`. How do you expect `return file_details` wot work without that argument?

Comment: Is `f` not serving as that argument? Or when I call `print(x.why())` do I need to pass something to it?

Comment: When you call `read_file()` it *does* pass `f`: `self.why(f)`. But you should see clearly that nothing is being passed to why when you call it like `print(x.why())`.

Comment: Have you tried `python -c "from run_test import Update; x = Update('my_file.json'); x.read_file()"`

Comment: @MarkMeyer - thanks. Since `read_file` is passing `f` to `why`, then when you call print(`read_file())`, shouldn't that print the dictionary `file_details`?

Comment: @RaghavGupta - thanks, I forgot to change that in my code when I posted. It's updated now.

Comment: So you have a class which contains different functions. `__init__` specifies the initial object and takes your config_file_name. The important thing to understand here is as soon as you call the class, nothing other than `__init__` gets executed. You have to call the functions seperately in order to solve your problems. The function `why()` has no clue that there is a function called `readfile()` which is to be executed and it's output have to be returned in his body.

Comment: You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module to convert JSON formatted files and data into Python data-structures (like dictionaries) and vice versa. I strongly suggest you try using it…